# CDK construct for a StepFunctions task that is only known during state machine execution

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I have a StepFunctions state machine defined with JSON, that is able to take ARNs of arbitrary ECS tasks (created elsewhere with CloudFormation), execute them and do some post-processing. The ECS task definition takes the task ARN from the input - it boils down to this:

```
       "States": {
          "Run Fargate Task": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:${AWS::Partition}:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "Parameters": {
              "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
              "Cluster": "${ecsClusterArn}",
              "TaskDefinition.$": "$.ecs_task_arn"
            },
            "ResultPath": null
          }
```

I am migrating this stack to CDK using the aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions Python module, but I can't find a way to pass the task ARN. I would like to do something like this:

```
import aws_cdk, constructs
from aws_cdk import aws_stepfunctions, aws_stepfunctions_tasks, aws_ecs

class StepsStack(aws_cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: constructs.Construct, construct_id: str, *, cluster: aws_ecs.ICluster, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        state_machine = aws_stepfunctions.StateMachine(
            None,
            "MyStateMachine",
            definition=aws_stepfunctions_tasks.EcsRunTask(
                self,
                "RunFargateTask",
                cluster=cluster,
                launch_target=aws_ecs.LaunchType("FARGATE"),

                # doesn't work, aws_ecs.TaskDefinition is expected:
                task_definition=aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at("$.ecs_task_arn"),
            ),
        )
```

It looks like CDK expects me to know exactly which ECS tasks I'll be running. Is there a way to express this dynamic behaviour in CDK?

Comment: You may have to resort to the CfnStateMachine Level 1 construct. Or use one of the other escape hatches, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html

Comment: Thanks @aax, your comment pushed me in the right direction. The escape hatches didn't work for me because they rely on CloudFormation idioms, and my issue was within the Amazon States Language. But CDK allows creating a CustomState object, which takes the raw Amazon States Language json. That did the trick!